# how to change background color if the matrix columns are equal

Tags: database, powerbi, visualization, powerquery, conditional-formatting

I am having issue in changing background in matrix table in Power BI.
I tried few things but did not succeed.

Idea is presented in image below.

[image]

Please let me know if you have some Idea how to write DAX formula for this.

Comment: Check out the update that I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is not officially supported by PBI use conditional formatting and for formatted by use the following measure [Field Value] option.

```
COLOUR EQUAL ROW = 

IF  (HASONEVALUE(TABLE[VALUE1])
    ,IF( MAX(TABLE[VALUE1] = MAX(TABLE[VALUE2])
        ,"lightgreen"
        ,"white"
    )
    ,BLANK()
)
```

[image]

**UPDATE :**
I have added the edited measure and it worked. Please use MAX instead of earlier.
[image]

This is available in conditional formatting. and select the measure

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did not resolve the issue. 
When I want to change filed values power bi does not let me add any of columns from data set instead of using VALUE1 = VALUE2

Comment: @nemd I don’t get what you are saying can you please explain with a image please

Comment: here - IF( EARLIER(TABLE[VALUE1] = EARLIER(TABLE[VALUE2])
basically when I want to swap table[VALUE1] with my column in dataset it is showing me that power bi cannot find any name to replace.. That's strange

Comment: @nemd this measure is wrong please take my suggestion in the answer. Check if the one value is returning from the data.

Comment: I do understand what this is wrong, but I just copy you a part where is a issue. 
If I add column in first part of expression in HASONEVALUE(), after that I cannot add anything to the part I have copied in previous comment. 
Hope you understand now

Comment: Ahhh ha the intellisence is not recognizing your column!!

Comment: I want to point out that this is matrix so I assume that with your expression I am able to compare values from the same column but with different sub-categories? 
Maybe this is the issue not intellisence?

Comment: @nemd Please check the update that i have posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242519/discussion-between-nemd-and-amilamgunawardana).